# Preg_replace in following string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to replace content from below string,

I want to replace line `The part has been repaired to` upto end p tag.

```
$text = "<p>701082 Range Control Board from Dacor is a manufacturer approved part. The part has been repaired to Dacor's specifications resulting in the highest performance with superior quality</p>";

preg_replace('/The part has been repaired to.*?<\/p>/U', '</p>', $text);

print_r($text);
```

I tried above preg_replace function but its not working as expected.

Comment: So you want to replace everything to the end of the string with a </p>. so your string becomes `<p>701082 Range Control Board from Dacor is a manufacturer approved part.</p>`

Comment: Why regex? https://3v4l.org/tR5tt

Comment: @NorrisOduro Yes,

Comment: check my answer

Comment: make sure you consider @Andreas answer If you need something other than regex. And dont forget to mark my answer if it is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preg_replace` function returns the value of the string after the pattern has been applied to it. Assign a the result to a variable and `print_r` the variable.

```
$text = "<p>701082 Range Control Board from Dacor is a manufacturer approved part. The part has been repaired to Dacor's specifications resulting in the highest performance with superior quality</p>";

$result  = preg_replace('/The part has been repaired to.*?<\/p>/U', '</p>', $text);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strpos to find the position of your "end" and use substr to substring it.

```
$text = "<p>701082 Range Control Board from Dacor is a manufacturer approved part. The part has been repaired to Dacor's specifications resulting in the highest performance with superior quality</p>";

Echo substr($text, 0, strpos($text, "The part has been repaired to")). "</p>";
```

https://3v4l.org/tR5tt